# Is it possible to create a database under database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Apologies if im mistaken.

I'm newbie to MySQL and using phpMyAdmin as GUI tool.

I wonder if I can create a database under database for hierarchical structure.

For now, I can only create tables under a database.

If it's impossible what are the alternatives for hierarchical databases?

Comment: The alternatives depend on what you want to do. You can create several databases in parallel. Or, what many applications do to support accounts which grant only a single database to a user (typical for cheap web hosters), you use a fixed prefix string for your tables. That way you can at least "group" the tables.

Comment: What do you mean by "hierarchical database"?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. You cannot create a database inside another database.